# Java Spring boot application with OpenCv : UnsatisfiedLinkError under Eclipse if use spring-boot-devtools

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, spring-boot, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have made a Spring boot application (1.4.0) with OpenCv dependency also. 
I installed and configured OpenCv on my mac, I did must compile it for mac... I made a link in java_home/jre/lib/ to the external library /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java320.dylib .

If I run the jar from terminal (not under eclipse) all it's all right, but if I run the application under Eclipse it can't find the native library and  I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J when I make Mat matScreenshot = Imgcodecs.imread(absolutePathScreenshot);

I found an usefull post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3315 that take me to the right way: in my pom.xml I included the dependency spring-boot-devtools that conflict with the System.loadLibrary ...

When I turn off the dependency, the application run correctly under Eclipse too.

I found this solution after days of research, I put this 'answer' here hoping it will be helpfull

Comment: THANKS!!! I solved this thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

For add OpenCV module to spring-boot project i add dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
   <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Ater it I remove library from java build path, wich added manualy earlier.

For init library:

```
OpenCV.loadShared();
```

In service:

```
Mat m = Imgcodecs.imread("F:\\ocr\\source\\1081672810_44O0UXXMF0I4UJTG.jpg", 1);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("F:\\ocr\\destination\\test.jpg", m);
```

Profit.